# Django Using reverse() with multiple URLs that include the same app

Tags: django, api, reverse

EDIT: I'm using rest_framework.reverse and providing the app name not the namespace for the reverse lookup. An example reverse call is:

```
reverse('api_app:system-detail', kwargs={...}, request=self.context.get('request'))
```

So I have a django project with a single app, and I have two different url patterns mapped to this one app. I currently have this mostly working, however for a few cases using reverse() results in the wrong namespace. My base urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include('api_project.api_app.urls', 
    namespace='api')),
    url(r'^beta/api/', include('api_project.api_app.urls', 
    namespace='beta')),
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='api', permanent=False), 
    name='index')
]
```

EDIT: api_app.urls looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from . import views
from rest_framework.schemas import get_schema_view

schema_view = get_schema_view(title="Schema")


app_name = 'api_app'

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.APIRoot.as_view(), name='api-root'),
url(r'^schema/$', schema_view, name'api-schema'),
....
```

In most cases reverse works as expected, e.g. using /beta/endpoint has links on the page that look like:

```
/beta/endpoint/example
```

However, in a few cases using /beta/endpoint has links like:

```
/api/endpoint/different-example
```

My question is less about how reverse determines which namespace to use, but instead is this the appropriate way to use two namespaces for the same app? Is this something I should approach completely differently?

Most of my research so far has not resulted in much success, so I'm thinking this might be fundamentally the wrong approach.

If this approach is okay, then I'm curious why reverse is inconsistent in which namespace it returns.

Comment: The namespace used in reverse is explicitly given by you: `reverse('beta:my_url')` or `{% url 'api:my_url' %}`. So I don't understand the question "how does reverse determine which namespace to use"?

Comment: I'm using the app name not the namespace in reverse. so it's reverse('api_app:my_url')

Comment: which Django version?

Comment: Edited the question to include this info, also forgot to mention this is using reverse from django rest framework. Using django version 2.1.1 and drf version 3.8.2

Comment: I think [this description](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls) shows you what happens. Are you trying to run two instances of the same app? In which case it looks like you sometimes end up in case 4.

Comment: that does look like what it's doing, I'll have to look into what's going on there. There are technically two instances, but I would expect the current_app to always be available so it wouldn't need to default to the last used. Thanks for the info!

Comment: It's not the "last used", it's the "last registered/deployed". Which in your case is "beta". So I don't understand the wrong links.

Comment: I looked and actually had a few cases where I was still using `reverse('api:my_url')`, so that does make sense, with everything now using `reverse('api_app:my_url')` I am only seeing: `/beta/example` when I expect: `/api/example`

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks again for clearing up the issue. Maybe you can post it as answer which might be helpful next time :)

Comment: But apparently it’s still not resolved as @jeremyverde is still seeing the wrong links?

Comment: @dirkgroten I would consider this resolved now, I've confirmed in my code that since there is no current_app attribute, reverse() is using the last defined instance. You also answered the main question of 'is this approach okay?' If you want to post a summary of these two things, I'll accept it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation on [reversing namespaced URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls) shows you what happens. In your case, you are instantiating the same app twice, once with the instance namespace `api` and one with the instance namespace `beta`.

Your application namespace is `api_app`, as defined by the `app_name` variable in your included urls.py file. So it doesn't match any of the two instance namespaces, meaning there is no default application instance.

So in your case, the URL resolver will mostly resolve to case 4: If you don't specify your `current_app` in the view, it will resolve to the last deployed instance (meaning the last registered), which is "beta".

You should specify your `current_app` in your view, both when using `reverse` and on the `request` object (so that your templates can also resolve correctly).